# How to improve on a case when private function needs to call a public function?

Tags: java, design-patterns, constructor

Here is a code sample that has 2 constructors, one empty and the other one which takes a matrix.
The client can either call the empty constructor and then pass in array individually to invoke the add function OR call the second constructor, which takes a matrix.

My only disappointment here is a private function 'addAll' calling a public function 'add'.

Is there any way to improve on this(meaning private function calling public method) without using the for loop inside the constructor ?

```
public class MergeNSortedArray {

    private PriorityQueue<ArrayContainer> heap;
    int totalLength;

    public MergeNSortedArray() {
        heap = new PriorityQueue<MergeNSortedArray.ArrayContainer>();
    }

    public MergeNSortedArray(int[][] matrix) {
        addAll(matrix);
    }


    private void addAll(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int[] a : matrix) {
            add(a);
        }
    }

    public void add(int a[]) {
        totalLength += a.length;
        heap.add(new ArrayContainer(a));
    }
```

Comment: i don't see that code bad..even you can make addAll public with class final or method final

Comment: You are right to worry about a private method calling a public one since the public one can be overridden in child classes. One possible solution is to create a private add(...) method that the public one calls and that the addAll(...) method also calls.

Comment: I see far larger pitfalls with your class being open to inheritance but seemingly not designed for it.  How do you expect `totalLength` to interact with `heap` and how have you accounted for someone changing the present behavior in a theoretical subclass?  You may be missing a private method to which the public method just delegates?

Comment: Make the class or methods final?  I agree ... this class does not seem like it is built (or intended) for inheritance.  So why allow it?

Comment: If the class is just locked down through use of `final` then make sure the system as a whole does not also become locked down.  Since there's no type of inheritance on the class I'm guessing it's being used directly as a concrete class.  From someone who has been stuck with complex ways to add small bits of functionality...introduce an interface or similar reference type flex point unless this code is totally disposable or used in places where that flexibility already exists.

Comment: After glancing at your code again...there are several other issues, Best practice is normally that only one constructor is the "real" constructor and the others call that constructor.  Where is `heap` initialized with the single arg constructor?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper Judging from the public `add()` method it seems you want a mutable object. Could you explain why `addAll()` should be private since the same result can basically be attained with multiple `add()`s ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make this class `final`? It seems only to be a utility class, so there should be no reason for anyone to subclass it.